# Pointer to a vector item -- On Windows

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following classes:

```
class A {};

class B { vector<A> vect; };
```

I can access an arbitrary A like this:

```
A a = b.vect[0];
// A *a_ptr = &a;
```

But how can I get directly to *a_ptr?

```
A *a_ptr = &b.vet[0];
```

compiles and doesn't give runtime errors, but it points to a wrong memory location.

**EDIT:**

my real world example: http://ideone.com/kP8NK

While Ideone gives the expected "`You are now at 0, 0, 0`", MS VisualStudio compiler yields "`You are now at 6624656, -33686019, -1414812757`"

Comment: What do you mean by "it points to wrong memory location"?, BTW doing this is dangerous as the next `push_back` might invalidate this pointer.

Comment: getting a_ptr.Field value gives me the wrong value while a.Field is correct

Comment: you would have to do a_ptr -> Field

Comment: @pistacchio: that is not possible, as `A a = b.vect[0]` copies the object from the same location from where you are taking the pointer.

Comment: why don't you use references, it's what the `operator[]` of vector returns anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not "wrong", you just missed the difference. Namely:

```
A a = b.vect[0]; // Makes `a` a *copy* of the vector element
A *a_ptr = &a; // Address of the copy

A *a_ptr2 = &b.vect[0]; // Address of the element, not a copy
```

To get the equivalence, you should change your first one to:

```
A& a = b.vect[0]; // Makes `a` a reference to the vector element
A *a_ptr = &a; // Address of the element, not a copy
```

If you're still not getting what you expect after observing this difference, then you'll need to show us your exact example along with how you're determining what "right" and "wrong" outcomes are.

---

The problem is that `std::vector<>::push_back` will invalidate references, pointers, and iterators to elements when `size() == capacity()`, because it needs to allocate a new chunk of memory. Using an invalidated pointer (et al.) leads to undefined behavior, so your results are unknown.

You should store indices instead, and do a trivial look-up to get the actual element. (Note `vector` remains ordered, so even though your rooms may move in memory, their index is the same.)

Comment: I don't think this makes sense cause vector is returning a reference, not a copy of object

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, it's returning a reference, but `a` is not a reference type, it's a value type; so to initialize it a copy (of the reference) is made.

Comment: true, but what's the difference of taking address from reference returned by method, or initialized with a return value?

Comment: @Oleg: They will be different. (We now know this issue isn't what the OP was having trouble with, though.)

Answer (score 2):

`A *a_ptr = &b.vect[0];` is correct. If it does not work for you then you are doing something else or you are modifying the vector after you obtain the pointer. Vector modifications generally invalidate all pointers and iterators at its elements.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me (after changing `vet` to `vect`). See http://ideone.com/V3tGS for proof.

Comment: `class A { public: ... };`? Ew. :) `struct A { ... };`.

Comment: that was a typo as the posted example is a simplification of the real code that you can now see in the EDIT

Comment: @GMan: I wanted to make the fewest changes possible to OP's code. Otherwise we get a comeback question: "Why did you change `class` to `struct`?"

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you modify the vector after taking the address to the pointer. Here:

```
 World w;
    w.worldMap.push_back(Room(0, 0, 0)); // starting point
    Room *starting_room = &w.worldMap[0];

    w.worldMap.push_back(Room(1, 1, 5)); // treasure room
    Room treasure_room = w.worldMap[1];
```

Modifying container invalidates all the pointers/references.

If you remove these lines:

```
    w.worldMap.push_back(Room(1, 1, 5)); // treasure room
    Room treasure_room = w.worldMap[1];
```

It works perfect